# Python single line if-else via dictionary

Tags: python

For example, we have an if-else statement which could be reduced to a single line:

```
condition = True
# condition = False

if condition:
    foo = 'Whatever'
else:
    foo = 'Nevermind'
```

The default reduce-technique is to do that:

```
foo = 'Whatever' if condition else 'Nevermind'
```

But also we can do it this way:

```
foo = {True:'Whatever', False:'Nevermind'}[condition]
```

Is that good/bad? Why?
Is there any other way to shrink if-else statement?
IMHO, in the dict-case readability is pretty cool since we can see all possible condition values in a well-structured form.

Comment: Now try to replace `"Nevermind"` and `"Whatever"` with expensive function calls. If both calls take 1 minute, how long do you think either technique will take? (Hint: the conditional expression *short-circuits*).

Comment: And which one do you think is more readable?

Comment: @MartijnPieters so the question cannot be answered in your opinion...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: the question is already answered, in the duplicate. Which one you pick is perhaps opinion-based, but I've hinted strongly at mine.

Comment: oh and a lot of techniques are already described. good.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: also, this question is too broad, it is not asking for one, it is asking for *all* techniques.

Comment: agreed. so OP will be happy with the 257 answers of the original Q&A.